# ON DUPLICATE KEY with bound params inside foreach

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to insert/update a list of items and their descriptors. They are dynamically populated and values grabbed as arrays via post.

However it seems that they can't be recognized as duplicate keys in this manner?

```
// Inputs being used
// <input type="hidden" name="menu-id[]" value="' . $page_id . '">
// <input type="hidden" name="menu-title[]" value="' . $page_title . '">
// <input type="hidden" name="menu-permalinks[]" value="' . $page_permalink . '">

$sql = "INSERT INTO 'menu' (`position`, `nav_id`, `nav_title`, `nav_permalink`)
        VALUES (?,?,?,?
        ON DUPLICATE KEY
        UPDATE `position`=VALUES(`position`), `nav_id`=VALUES(`nav_id`), `nav_title`=VALUES(`nav_title`), `nav_permalink`=VALUES(`nav_permalink`);";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("iiss", $param_pos, $param_id, $param_title, $param_permalink);

// Arrays from hidden input fields
$current_ids = $_POST['menu-id'];
$current_titles = $_POST['menu-title'];
$current_permalinks = $_POST['menu-permalinks'];

foreach ($current_ids as $key => $current_id) {
  $param_pos = '';
  $param_id = $current_id;
  $param_title = $current_titles[$key];
  $param_permalink = $current_permalinks[$key];

  $stmt->execute();
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

This will add duplicate records and I only want the new ones!

Thanks for any ideas.

Edit:

Primary Key is `id` and auto-increments

Comment: what is the primary key column name?

Comment: -Yeah, that's what I tought, what you want is not possible since `ON DUPLICATE KEY ...` only checks the primary key, not alle unique indexes-

Comment: Sorry, I am wrong, it should work if you have a Unique Index on the column!

Comment: Oh wow, didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: Read this if you want more information https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html